# getting the value of json response php ajax

Tags: json, ajax

How can I get the `product_price` value from the following JSON?

```
success: function(response){
    if (response.data.product_id == true) {
        alert("Success");
        alert(response.data.product_price.val());
    {
    "data": {
        "product_id": true,
        "product_price": "434",
        "product_name": "yahoo",
        "product_long_description": "asdfasdf",
        "product_care": "yess",
        "product_image": "\/easyinteriors\/public_html\/product_images\/144257317733697.jpg"
    }
}

alert(response.data.product_price);
```

I'm getting null value

Comment: You need to provide your entire JSON  and your entire AJAX function

Comment: how can i do this can you please elobrate it

Comment: Do you get a value from `response.data.product_price.value`?

Comment: No I didn't get the value response.data.product_price.value using it

Comment: Edit your original question and add your entire AJAX JavaScript code so we can see what you're doing

Comment: Also, when you edit, make sure to add the entire JSON or php that creates your JSON

Comment: The given code is invalid. I just edited the tabs to make it readable and the braces cause an error, and why is the data object inside a function? Please provide code that will reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code:

`alert(response.data.product_price);`

Comment: used getting null value

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning data into json format. You need to parse the response

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response);
```

then `alert(json.data.product_price);`

Comment: Please elaborate it more.